# Are there ways to call two functions (one just after another) in purely functional language? (in non-io mode)

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying to understand order of execution in purely functional language.

I know that in purely functional languages, there is no necessary execution order.

So my question is:

Suppose there are two functions.
I would like to know all ways in which I can call one function after another (except nested call of one function from another) (and except io-mode).

I would like to see examples in Haskell or pseudo-code.

Comment: You can't call one function after another at all. Perhaps you're thinking of procedures, which other languages erroneously call functions!

Comment: You mean call a function, ignore it's return value and then call another function? Why would you want to do that in a non-IO context? Since functions don't have side effects, calling a function and then ignoring its result doesn't really accomplish much.

Comment: To David Young: I'm just trying to understand how to live in the world of purely functional language.

Comment: @uintptr_t Could you please give an example of some scenario you'd like to see how it's expressed in a purely functional language?

Comment: "In the world of purely functional language," you never need to care what order functions are executed in.

Comment: @Ariel D. Moya Sequeira I don't know such scenario. I just can't clearly understand how to write purely functional programs.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do what you describe, if the functions are totally independent and you don't use the result of one when you call the other.

This is because there is no reason to do this. In a side effect free setting, calling a function and then ignoring its result is exactly the same as doing nothing for the amount of time it takes to call that function (setting aside memory usage).

It is *possible* that `seq x y` will evaluate `x` and then `y`, and then give you `y` as its result, but this evaluation order isn't guaranteed.

Now, if we *do* have side effects, such as if we are working inside a Monad or Applicative, this could be useful, but we aren't *truly* ignoring the result since there is context being passed implicitly. For instance, you can do

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, " >> putStrLn "world"
```

in the IO Monad. Another example would be the list Monad (which could be thought of as representing a nondeterministic computation):

```
biggerThanTen :: Int -> Bool
biggerThanTen n = n > 10

example :: String
example = filter biggerThanTen [1..15] >> return 'a'  -- This evaluates to "aaaaa"
```

Note that even here we aren't *really* ignoring the result. We ignore the specific values, but we use the *structure* of the result (in the second example, the structure would be the fact that the resulting list from `filter biggerThanTen [1..15]` has 5 elements).

I should point out, though, that things that are sequenced in this way aren't necessarily evaluated in the order that they are written. You can sort of see this with the list Monad example. This becomes more apparent with bigger examples though:

```
example2 :: [Int]
example2 =
  [1,2,3] >>=
    (\x -> [10,100,1000] >>=
             (\y -> return (x * y)))   --  ==> [10,100,1000,20,200,2000,30,300,3000]
```

The main takeaway here is that evaluation order (in the absence of side effects like IO and ignoring bottoms) doesn't affect the ultimate meaning of code in Haskell (other than possible differences in efficiency, but that is another topic). As a result, there is never a reason to call two functions "one after another" in the fashion described in the question (that is, where the calls are totally independent from each other).

### Do notation

Do notation is actually exactly equivalent to using `>>=` and `>>` (there is actually one other thing involved that takes care of pattern match failures, but that is irrelevant to the discussion at hand). The compiler actually takes things written in do notation and converts them to `>>=` and `>>` through a process called "desugaring" (since it removes the syntactic sugar). Here are the three examples from above written with do notation:

***IO Example***

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello, "
  putStrLn "World"
```

***First list example***

```
biggerThanTen :: Int -> Bool
biggerThanTen n = n > 10

example :: String -- String is a synonym for [Char], by the way
example = do 
  filter biggerThanTen [1..15]
  return 'a'
```

***Second list example***

```
example2 :: [Int]
example2 = do
  x <- [1,2,3]
  y <- [10,100,1000]
  return (x * y)
```

Here is a side-by-side comparison of the conversions:

```
do          --
  m         --  m >> n
  n         --


do          --
  x <- m    -- m >>= (\x ->
  ...       --           ...)
```

The best way to understand do notation is to first understand `>>=` and `return` since, as I said, that's what the compiler transforms do notation into.

As a side-note, `>>` is just the same as `>>=`, it just ignores the "result" of it's left argument (although it preserves the "context" or "structure"). So all definitions of `>>` must be equivalent to `m >> n = m >>= (\_ -> n)`.

### Expanding the `>>=` in the second list example

To help drive home the point that Monads are not usually impure, lets expand the `>>=` calls in the second list example, using the Monad definition for lists. The definition is:

```
instance Monad [] where
  return x = [x]
  xs >>= f = concatMap f xs
```

and we can convert `example2` into:

***Step 0 (what we already have)***

```
example2 :: [Int]
example2 =
  [1,2,3] >>=
    (\x -> [10,100,1000] >>=
             (\y -> return (x * y)))
```

***Step 1 (converting the first `>>=`)***

```
example2 =
  concatMap
    (\x -> [10,100,1000] >>=
              (\y -> return (x * y)))
    [1,2,3]
```

***Step 2***

```
example2 =
  concatMap
    (\x -> concatMap
             (\y -> return (x * y))
             [10,100,1000])
    [1,2,3]
```

***Step 3***

```
example2 =
  concatMap
    (\x -> concatMap
             (\y -> [x * y])
             [10,100,1000])
    [1,2,3]
```

So, there is no magic going on here, just normal function calls.

Comment: I like your answer but it is still hard to grasp it for me. When I tried to find real world Haskell examples I saw that _do_ (or _IO_) is used a lot in these examples. So at the first glance it looks similar to imperative programs. Could you please give me an example of real world Haskell program where there are a lot of purely functional code and minimal usage of _do_ and _IO_.

Comment: @uintptr_t: Actually, just because something uses `do`, that doesn't necessarily mean it is impure or that it uses IO. `do` notation actually gets converted into calls to `>>=` and `>>`. I added some more information in my answer about do notation (which I know is sort of the opposite of what you asked here, but I wanted to point out that `do` and Monads are totally separate from the idea of purity and IO). For lists, `xs >>= f = concatMap f xs` so there is no impurity going on there, for example. In fact, IO is the *exception* to the rule. Most Monads exclusively involve pure function calls.

Comment: @uintptr_t I think the reason you find it hard to understand how this could work is lack of experience. I suggest a good tutorial like [Learn you a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). Once you're used to lots of examples of pure functions it becomes clearer why this works. What you're saying is equivalent to looking at code for the first time and saying "How is this an app? How can this be the game I play?" It's hard to answer that question without teaching you how to code first - same for pure functional programming - it's a new way of thinking with few short explanations.

Comment: Wondering if the part about `seq` is accurate: `but this evaluation order isn't guaranteed.`

Comment: @funct7 It is true that a specific evaluation order for `seq` is not guaranteed by the Haskell standard. The only thing that is guaranteed is that *both* arguments of `seq` are evaluated to WHNF by the time the `seq` call is finished being evaluated (if it is evaluated in the first place). This is described in the docs for the Prelude [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq). See also [this section of the Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1260006.2)

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function whose arguments depend on the evaluation of another function:

```
-- Ads the first two elements of a list together
myFunc :: [Int] -> Int
myFunc xs = (head xs) + (head $ tail xs)
```

If that's what you mean.  In this case, you can't get the output of `myFunc xs` without evaluating `head xs`, `head $ tail xs` and `(+)`.  There is an order here.  However, the compiler can choose which order to execute `head xs` and `head $ tail xs` in since they are not dependent on each other, but it can't do the addition without having both of the other results.  It could even choose to evaluate them in parallel, or on different machines.  The point is that pure functions, because they have no side effects, don't have to be evaluated in a given order until their results are interdependent.

---

Another way to look at the above function is as a graph:

```
                            myFunc
                              |
                             (+)
                            /   \
                           /     \
                         head    head
                           \      |
                            \    tail
                             \  /
                              xs
```

In order to evaluate a node, all nodes below it have to be evaluated first, but different branches can be evaluated in parallel.  First `xs` must be evaluated, at least partially, but after that the two branches can be evaluated in parallel.  There are some nuances due to lazy evaluation, but this is essentially how the compiler constructs evaluation trees.

---

If you really want to force one function call before the other, you can use the `seq` function.  It takes two arguments, forces the first to be evaluated, then returns the second, e.g.

```
myFunc2 :: [Int] -> Int
myFunc2 xs = hxs + (hxs `seq` (head $ tail xs))
    where hxs = head xs
```

This will force `head xs` to evaluate before `head $ tail xs`, but this is more dealing with strictness than sequencing functions.

Comment: Is it only way? Suppose `func1` and `func2` are independent. How to call one after another? (in unnecessary order)

Comment: You can use the `seq` function that forces its first argument to be evaluated before evaluating the second, but usually this sort of computation is pointless in Haskell.  Since there are no side effects, evaluating one before the other (if they're independent) doesn't matter.

Comment: Let me add a couple of nitpicks. The order graph idea is harder to apply when non-strict functions are used. E.g. reducing `f x ++ g x` to WHNF will not cause `g x` to be called unless `f x` is the empty list. Also, quite counter-intuitively, `seq x y` is not required to evaluate `x` evaluated before `y`, but is merely required to evaluate to bottom whenever `x` is bottom: the implementation could evaluate `y` first, then `x`, and then return the result of `y`. Instead `pseq x y' does guarantee that `x` is evaluated first, since we really need that to force parallel evaluation.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an easy way:

```
case f x of
    result1 -> case g y of
        result2 -> ....
```

Still, unless `g y` uses something from result1 and the subsequent calculations something from `result2`, or the pattern is such that the result must be evaluated, there is no guarantee that either of `f` or `g`  are actually called, nor in what order.

Still, you wanted a way to call one function after another, and this is such a way.

Comment: Pattern matching with a variable pattern does NOT force the evaluation of the term begin matched. Evaluation only happens if the (non-lazy) pattern involves a constructor. (Quite confusingly, in the GHC Core language it instead DOES evaluate the term)

Comment: @chi You did read and understand the paragraph I wrote after the code example? I think it makes it clear that `result1` and `result2` are (meta) variables for strict patterns. And in any way, no matter what is evaluated when, it remains a valid way to "call one function after another".

Comment: Point taken, I missed that comment indeed :-P. Still, I would not call this "calling a function after another", and I believe the OP was not asking for this. I do understand that this is a terminology issue, though, so every opinion is arguable. (BTW, I did not downvote your answer.)

Comment: @chi The downvote is not my concern. But look, "after" could have two meanings: temporal and spatial. In a temporal sense, clearly the case construct calls one function after the other, as it is not a language construct for parallelism. And in a spatial sense, the application of `g` comes after that of `f` in the program text .... so there is no terminology issue, unless I missed a meaning of "after".

Comment: Would you also consider `let x1 = f x in let x2 = g x in ...` an acceptable solution? Or even `let x1 = f x ; x2 = g x in ...`? Assuming so, in a spatial sense I would agree with you on these. In a temporal sense, less so, since no specific evaluation order is mandated by Haskell, and I tend to identify evaluation order with "time".

Comment: @chi this is, IMHO, the difference between let and case. let can and will be reordered, not so nested case.