# What is the category of bugs that monads prevent?

Tags: monads, defects

My understanding is that for the do monad, each step has a continuation and a closure.

This [author writes](https://github.com/mightybyte/purity-types-monads/blob/master/purity-types-monads.md):

> We've seen that purity, strong types, and monads can:
>
> ...
>
> - Prevent bugs that might arise from confusion between different phases of execution.

My question is: **What is the category of bugs that monads prevent?**

Comment: That has more to do with the purity and strong types part than the monad part. Also, do isn't a monad, it's just a shorthand for calling the `Monad` methods.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful - could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: Well, monads are a bit notoriously tricky to explain without spreading misconceptions. Have you seen this article yet? http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html. Also, I wrote an answer that I feel explains a specific kind of monad decently well and that may help (it was written in response to a question from someone trying to avoid monads): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188645/non-monadic-error-handling-in-haskell/23207315. Unfortunately these don't really go into the bug prevention aspect of strong typing, I'll have to think about other resources for that.

Comment: One other piece of advice I can give is definitely the best way to learn about `Monad` is to look at *specific* monads. Once you look at and use them enough of them for long enough, you start to get a mental picture of how this generalizes to the more general idea of a "monad." Try to make sure that you don't think that just because one instance of `Monad` works in a certain way, all of them must work in that certain way though.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've written an algorithm that must receive a callback.  You don't know what the callback will want to do, or what it's capable of.  The most generic way to accept such a callback is to receive a function like:

```
Monad m => a -> m b
```

This gives complete freedom to your caller (who can chose any `m` that is a Monad), while denying any such freedom to your library.  This prevents the introduction of side-effects in an otherwise pure library, while allowing side-effects to occur if the caller desires them.

I've used this pattern before in a pure register allocator.  In that library I never needed effects myself, but wanted to allow the user to make use of their own effects (such as State) for creating new blocks and move instructions.

Answer (score 0):

### Effect separation

Like ordinary types give you a way to distinguish *data*, monads give you a way to distinguish *effects*.

#### Elixir

Here is an example in `Elixir`, which is a nearly-pure functional language on top of Erlang. This example is derived from a real-world situation that occurs very often at my work.

```
def handle_call(:get_config_foo, _, state) do:
  {:reply, state.foo, state}
end

def handle_call(:get_bar, _, state) do:
  {:reply, state.bar, state}
end

def handle_call({:set_bar, bar}, _, state) do:
  {:reply, :ok, %{state | bar: bar}}
end
```

This defines an API of a [GenServer](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html), which is a little Erlang node that holds some `state` and allows you to query it as well as change it. The first call, `:get_config_foo` reads an *immutable config setting*. The second set of calls, `:get_bar` and `{:set_bar, bar}`, gets and sets a *mutable state variable*.

How I wish I had monads here, to prevent the following bug:

```
def handle_call({:set_bar, bar}, _, state) do:
  {:reply, :ok, %{state | foo: bar}}
end
```

Can you spot the mistake? Well, I just *wrote a readonly value*. Nothing in Elixir prevents this. You can't mark some parts of your GenServer state as readonly, and others als read-write.

### Haskell: Reader and State

In Haskell you can use different monads to specify different kinds of effects. Here are readonly state (`Reader`) and read-write state:

```
data Reader r a = Reader (r -> a)
data State s a = State (s -> (a, s))
```

`Reader` allows you to access the config state `r` to return some value `a`. `State` allows you to read the state, return some value *and* to modify the state. Both are monads, which essentially means that you can chain those state accesses sequentially in an imperative fashion. In `Reader` you can first read one config setting, and then (based on that first setting), read another setting. In `State`, you can read the state, and then (based on what you read) modify it in a further way. But you can *never* modify the state in `Reader` while you execute it.

### Deterministic effects

Let me repeat this. Binding several calls to `Reader` assures you that you can *never* modify the reader state inbetween. If you have `getConfigFoo1 :: Reader Config Foo1` and `getConfigFoo2 :: Foo1 -> Reader Config Foo2` and you do `getAllConfig = getConfigFoo1 >>= getConfigFoo2`, then you have *certainty* that both queries will run on the same `Config`. Elixir does not have this feature and allows the above mentioned bug go unnoticed.

Other effects where this is useful is `Writer` (write-only state, e.g. logging) and `Either` (exception handling). When you have `Writer` instead of `Reader` or `State`, you can be sure that your state is ever only appended to. When you have `Either`, you know exactly the type of exceptions that can occur. This is all much better than using `IO` for logging and exception handling.